# Function "who am I" accessible from function and usable as key?

Tags: haskell

I would like to use a collection of function names as Data.Map keys, and have the key for each function automatically available from within that function. I am willing to consider "unsafe" operations, if necessary.

My specific programming problem is this: I've been developing a simple parser library for textual transformations, which I use in particular for preprocessing and grooming all of my Haskell code. It has the virtue of being small enough to easily hack, with most constructs not requiring explicit monadic do notation. Instead, grammars read almost verbatim like their formal descriptions.

In particular, I've entered the lexical structure of Haskell2010 *once*, with the idea of modifying this grammar in various ways for different applications. I do this now by creating labels corresponding to each grammar construct, and passing these labels to each construct. I also use these labels as keys for Data.Map. This allows me to provide post-processing for various labels, in different applications of my grammar.

The details of my code don't really matter; the gist of my question should be clear, for any similar application to what I describe here. Here is a (draft) fragment of the grammar for Haskell2010:

```
program = Program §
  many $ lexeme ∨ whitespace

lexeme = Lexeme §
  reservedop ∨ reservedid ∨ qvarid ∨ qconid ∨ qvarsym ∨ qconsym ∨ literal
  ∨ special

literal = Literal §
  integer ∨ float ∨ hchar ∨ hstring

special = Special §
  oneOf "(),;[]`{}"

whitespace = Whitespace §
  many1 whitestuff

whitestuff = Whitestuff §
  whitechar ∨ comment ∨ ncomment

whitechar  = Whitechar §
  newline ∨ vertab ∨ space ∨ tab ∨ uniWhite

newline = Newline §
  hreturn ◊ linefeed ∨ hreturn ∨ linefeed ∨ formfeed
```

Having worked hard to make grammars concise, I find this duplicate boilerplate very ugly. Why can't I just use the function names themselves, and have each function access its own name as needed? (The operators are monadic, so there's a chance to do anything we like, behind the scenes.)

I understand and enjoy the meta-game of arguments that explain why construct "X" in Lisp (Scheme) or any object-oriented language isn't necessary in Haskell, because one just does "Y". In comparison to Haskell, Lisp is both less disciplined and seemingly more flexible. Lisp reminds me of the early "Out of the Inkwell" cartoons at the birth of animation, where a hand could come out from behind the screen and redraw something to bend rules as needed.

From instead an object-oriented point of view (which like all religions I try to avoid) this is a rather routine use of "self". However, I don't want to create an entire object-oriented framework here, I just want a tiny bit of direct access to the symbol table (or the equivalent, whatever gets the job done), as these other languages offer one way or another.

So I'm embarrassed that I can't play this meta-game here. It appears to me that Haskell, tidily and with great discipline, seals off access to symbol tables and runtime environments that would let me golf this code, get rid of this eyesore boilerplate. Or not? I ask here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are talking about? Can you write two more lines: 1. I have .... 2. I want ....

Comment: 1. I have a parser, in which I've encoded the lexical structure of Haskell2010, taken from the report. I want to use this file in multiple ways, which entails modifying functions "in the middle" of this lengthy description. I understand the paradigm for doing this in other languages, but not in Haskell.

Comment: 2. I want to be able to use functions as (Show, Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum) keys for Data.Map. I want each function to be able to figure out its corresponding key automatically, without my explicit help. In other words, I rather directly want a tiny piece of the "self" functionality in an object-oriented language.

Comment: It sounds like you want _reflection_, but reflection is basically at odds with functional programming. Some Lisps have reflection but this turns them into multi-paradigm languages. At a push you could wrap functions in data types along with their name and other elements you want to reflect on; but I suspect you would find this ugly.

Comment: @Syzygies I'm confused. Is the code fragment (a) supposed to be valid Haskell source code, or is it (b) a data file from which your code will generate further Haskell code? If (b) I don't understand why your own code can't generate the duplication itself without it needing to be in your data file.

Comment: I think that to get better answers the question needs to be less political, but more specific, revealing more details about why the labels are needed and how they are used. This way, an alternative solution may be found without focusing too much on "self-reference". Also, the (in)significance of the parser being the Haskell parser has to be pointed out explicitly! Can "Haskell-2010" be replaced with "a language X"?

Comment: Yes, the code fragment is running Haskell code, which is why my question represents much of the code bloat. The question is of course political, or else I'd live with what I've got. Is this considered trolling? I have programmed extensively in each language under discussion. I understand how to answer other "how does one do X in Haskell?" questions but I'm very amused that this one has me stumped.

Comment: "or is it (b) a data file from which your code will generate further Haskell code?" It's (a), but it is the program by which I do (b) for all of my *other* projects, e.g. mix Haskell and TeX, support heredocs, lightweight "flush is comment, indented is code" literate Haskell. I'd have a bootstrapping problem if I needed to preprocess *this* code.

Comment: You may be interested in this blog post: http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2010/11/obtaining-name-of-function-in-haskell.html

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't do that in standard-compliant Haskell because that breaks referential transparency, but using GHC extension named [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/template-haskell.html), it can be done. Template Haskell allows you to run custom code in compile-time to generate boilerplate code or do something more interesting (you may want to transform the existing code to achieve your goal).

Comment: Look at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Mem-StableName.html Thinking about your answer, I could leverage a single crack in the wall of referential transparency into a mechanism for creating objects with the sense of self I need (and others might need). I was planning to use the foreign function interface, but "stable names" look like they already accomplish this.

Comment: You have to be careful with `StableName`s. To quote the docs, "if two stable names are not equal, then the objects they name may still be equal".